# Angular CLI, add Universal / server-side rendering

Tags: angular, angular-cli, universal, server-side-rendering

I have build an application based on angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.24.
I wanted to add universal based on tutorial from https://universal.angular.io/, but it wasn't working at all. I also tried universal-cli from https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cli, but after merging projects, there is too many errors. Command ung init --universal also not working as intended, even if I manage to get it to work, pre-render not working. Is there any other solution or i have to wait?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)

Comment: Maybe also take a look at angular-ssr

Comment: Have a look to the angular universal starter app https://github.com/angular/universal-starter